# How to find the required coefficients of the expansion of the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, trigonometry, determinant

I have a questionw where it's given that the determinant $\Delta(x)$ such that,
\begin{align*}
\Delta(x) 
&= 
\begin{vmatrix}
\cos(2x) & \sin^2(x) & \cos(4x) \\ 
\sin^2(x) & cos(2x) & \cos^2(x) \\
cos(4x) & \cos^2(x) & \cos(2x) \\ 
\end{vmatrix}\\
&=a_0+a_1\sin x +a_2\sin^2x+....
\end{align*}

In this question, I need to find the values of $a_0,a_1,a_2$.

Here's how I approached it, first, I put $x=0$ for both the LHS and RHS, this leaves me with only $a_0$ in the RHS and in the LHS, all the terms containing $\sin$ become $0$ and $\cos$ terms come out to be $1$, which yields the value $a_0=-1$

Then, I differentiated both sides of the equation and ended up with $3$ determinants (I differentiated column wise) and on the RHS, I got $\cos x$ as the coefficient of $a_1$, and now putting $x=0$, I also got that $a_1=0$.

But, I cannot get how to find out $a_2$, one way I thought was to divide the 1st derivative by $\cos x$ and then again differentiating but that complicates stuff a lot. Any help would be appreciated. The answer says that $a_2=18$

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account what you are asked for, let $t=\sin^{-1}(x)$ to make first
$$\Delta(t)=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1-2 t^2 & t^2 & 8 t^4-8 t^2+1 \\
 t^2 & 1-2 t^2 & 1-t^2 \\
 8 t^4-8 t^2+1 & 1-t^2 & 1-2 t^2
\end{array}
\right)$$ and now $u=t^2$. It is simple (done by hand).